# Cart table structure and update only particular item in cart

Tags: php, structure, shopping-cart

I am trying to design database for a simple online shopping cart. I am not getting the idea of what to place for the table shopping cart. Is not it ok to create cart id as primary key? And later on while updating the items in a cart, what would be the appropriate logic to update only the changed field (say quantity) of a particular product? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

An artificial PK (such as `cartID`, an auto-increment integer `PRIMARY KEY`) is almost always "just fine" (and I don't see why a table of shopping carts should be any different in this regard from others).  As for your other question -- what indication do you have of what fields were changed?  Why would it be any problem at all to `UPDATE` the table with *every* field, including those that weren't changed?

Answer (score 0):

Don't store your cart information in the database, you don't want to be making an UPDATE query every-time someone adds something to their cart or alters the quantity.

Use a session to keep an array of item numbers (ref the database ids of the items) and their quantity.

When the user is ready to 'checkout' just pull the item details from your session and build an 'order'.